# Application gets flooded by robots when I put a build online

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have a very big problem with Android Google Play Console.
When I put a build online, an army of robots (which I guess belong to Google) come and use my application.

The problem is that my application is an application that doesn't need an account because accounts are created automatically, so every time I put a build in internal testing, beta or production, I end up with about 50 new accounts and the robots completely destroy all my analytics.

I thought I could fix the problem by disabling the "pre-launch reports", but unfortunately, the problem persists.

How do I tell Google not to use my Application with its robots? Or is there a way to distinguish them from normal users?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you can't. You have to treat them like normal users as this is Google verifying your app that follows their policies.

Comment: I finally managed to contact Google support who told me exactly the same thing and also told me to make a distinction between the Pre-Launch Report bots and the review bots (which are mandatory and impossible to remove, unlike the Pre-Lauch Report bots).
So your answer confirms this! thank you